# Test Driven Development is a hoax?

Tags: tdd

Excuse me for the title a little provocative.I'll take an example. Suppose you need to write a program to build a car. Here's a test program:

```
public void testCarBuilder()
{
  expectedCar=someCar;
  actualCar=carFactory.build(bigWhell, yellowBodyCar);
  assertEqual(expectedCar, actualCar);
}
```

To know that to build a car, we need a function that will have the wheels and the carBody as parameter, it should at least have made ​​an analysis of the program. This analysis can be done in natural language, UML or even directly write in the programming language!. We can write this analysis on a piece of paper, leaving it in our brain, or in writing to a file.
Analysis is already a skeleton of a program! So it was always at least one program skeleton write before the test!
Say that development task starts  by writing tests is sybyllin, there is always a first skeleton program ( that we can call analysis)  to write before. Unless someone shows me how the opposite may be possible.

Comment: Unsuitable question on StackOvferlow, IMHO.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about development methologies.


Comment: TDD is an iterative method, just like most design paradigms nowadays. The tests are refined all the time, which is also known as *designing*. The problem with your example is that there are a lot of hidden assumptions. What are the requirements of a car? It probably should look like a car, so it should have wheels and a chassis. That's not design, those are requirements!

Comment: Analysis is a **process**, not a result. In a TDD approach you actually do some analysis, right before writing your test. That's why some people call it Test-Driven *Design*.

Comment: Thank Guillaume31.
I think the mistake i make is that. Analysis is a process, not a result. I would like to mark your answer as a good answer

Comment: TDD works even in this case. Before you have a skeleton, you can describe the requirements using BDD, for example a feature file written in Gherkin. The big insight there is that tests are an executable requirements specification. And you can specify requirements before you even start with the skeleton.

Answer (score 1):

Of ccourse some people write a test first.

In fact, you just wrote a test first in the question.
Your test has possibly then told you the code you need to write next, but you have discovered that *after* you wrote the test in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your question as if you want to know how the design emerges when doing TDD.

In order to write a test you must define some boundary/surface/facade that the test should interact with. This design activity is done up front. The design that grows and changes is the one that is on the other side of that test boundary.

In your (trivial) example, the design that the tests help you discover is the one inside the `carFactory`. That's not very helpful, so I would say that your test is not that good.

There are different school within TDD. The one I practise advocate that you test from the outside and in. You choose a test boundary that is as close as possible to the system boundary. For instance, you let your test simulate button clicks in the user interface. When doing this, you are free to make changes to the design of the whole system on the other side of that button click.

In your example, why do you want to create a car? What did the user do to trigger this code, and how can the user tell that whatever she wanted to accomplish worked? That's what you should have in your test.